# IndexOutOfRange exception when using int variable as array selector

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to create a very basic login system in C# using arrays for username and password comparing.

I'm using a `for()` loop to compare the username and password the user provides with the usernames and passwords that are in my arrays. Here's my loop code:

```
string user = null, usrpassword = null;
string[] usernames = {"admin", "guest"};
string[] userpasswords = {"adminpw", "guestpw"};

Console.Write("Username: "); //Username
user = Console.ReadLine();
Console.Write("Password: "); //Password
usrpassword = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Processing...");

for (int i = 0; i <= usernames.Length; i++)
{
    if (user == usernames[i] && usrpassword == userpasswords[i])
    {
        loginloop = false;
        Console.WriteLine("Login Successful.");
    }
    else if (i > usernames.Length)
    {
        //incorrect username
        Console.WriteLine("Incorrect username or password!");
    }
} //for-loop-end
```

I don't get any syntax errors when I build, but when it reaches the for loop it crashes and gives me a `IndexOutOfRange` exception.

Comment: Do you really want to rely on the indices of two different collections to find the password of a user? You could at least use a `Dictionary<string, string>` instead. The username is the key and the password is the value.

Answer (score 5):

Array indexes start at `0` and go up to `Length - 1`, so you only want to continue the loop while the iterator is less than `Length`.

Change the `<=` to a `<`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < usernames.Length; i++)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: @SindriKristján, if one of these posts answers your question, you should mark it as so. This way, other users with similar questions will see these answers more readily.

Answer (score 1):

You just have an "off by one" style error in your for loops conditions;

`for (int i = 0; i <= usernames.Length; i++)`

should instead be

`for (int i = 0; i < usernames.Length; i++)`

The array is "zero indexed" where as the `Length` property is the length counting from one to `n`. The final index is actually the value one less than `Length` or 0 in the case of an empty array.